# why ng-include can't fire stateChangeStart right? ui-router's bug?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

i'm learning by [angular-login-example](https://github.com/colthreepv/angular-login-example), it test authentication by $stateChangeStart

under is my test code

index.html:

```
<div ng-include="'test.html'"></div>
<div ui-view></div>
```

test.html

```
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl"></div>
```

app.js

```
    .config(function ($urlRouterProvider) {
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/topics');
    })
.config(function ($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
  .state('topics', {
    url: '/topics',
    template: '11111111'
  });
}),
        .controller('TestCtrl', function ($rootScope) {
          $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, to, toParams, from, fromParams) {
            console.log('xxxxxx');
          });
        })
```

if i visite http://localhost/, it will redirect to http://localhost/#/topics, and will output 'xxxxxx', but if i visite http://localhost/#/topics, output nothing!

if i don't use ng-include, that's said:

index.html

```
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl"></div>
```

either i visite http://localhost/ or http://localhost/#/topics, always output 'xxxxxx'?

is it ui-router's bug?

Comment: Please show all relevant code related to routing config

Comment: put controller in the route config and remove from `ng-controller`. Also template should have a root element usually

Comment: @charlietfl <div ng-include="'test.html'" ng-controller="TestCtrl"></div> like this?

Comment: no, assign the controller to the state

Comment: @charlietfl yes, <div ng-include="'test.html'" ng-controller="TestCtrl"></div> all right.

Comment: @charlietfl <div ng-include="'test.html'" ></div> has no state

Comment: then you haven't provided enough code. This is very confusing. Create a demo in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) that replicates problem

Comment: @charlietfl I think i found the problem, ng-include instantiate later than ui-view, so ng-include inside controller can't catch first stateChangeStart but second can be caught